# How to make a pointer in a function change the pointee in C

Tags: c, pointers

Hee guys,

I have been reading a couple of things about pointers and pointees and started getting curious. The only thing I dont understand is how pointers behave in functions, hence the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int pointeeChanger(char* writeLocation) {

    writeLocation = "something";
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{

    char crypted[] = "nothing";
    char* cryptedPointer = crypted;

    pointeeChanger(cryptedPointer);

    printf("The new value is: %s", cryptedPointer);

    return 0;
}
```

What my intention to do is to adjust the pointee, "crypted" var, through a pointer given to a function. The only thing is that it is not working. Could you please explain me what is going wrong in my thought process. I am fairly new to C so my errors could be fairly basic.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings,

Kipt Scriddy

Comment: C pointers as function parameters are confusing because textbooks often call this "passing by reference". It's not wrong, but they fail to mention that you could also call it "passing a pointer by copy". It's helpful if you think of it as a copy of a pointer, rather than a reference.

Comment: Also beware - not mentioned elsewhere - when you pass a pointer to a string constant like "nothing" and try to change the contents that are pointed to `writeLocation[4] = 'G';` you **may** get an error, because many system will place string constants in write-protected memory; that is, the memory page that holds the string has been marked to not allow writing. That is up to the OS and the MMU so what works on one system could fail on another. (We actually had a question about that on our "programmer's test" for hiring at one company I worked at)

Comment: Sudy the excellent C class at http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/cclass.html (not latest&greatest C, but should be enough for your present needs). Much material on C is at http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/

Comment: I would recommend you not only read up on what "passing by reference" means, but also study the meaning of the `reference` vs. the `de-reference` operator. It will really clear up things for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: `writeLocation` is a local variable and is a copy of `cryptedPointer`. When you modify `writeLocation`, `cryptedPointer` is not modified.

If you want to modify `cryptedPointer`, you have to pass a pointer to it, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int pointeeChanger(char** writeLocation) {            /* Note: char** */

    *writeLocation = "something";                     /* Note: *writeLocation */
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{

    char crypted[] = "nothing";
    char* cryptedPointer = crypted;

    pointeeChanger(&cryptedPointer);                  /* Note: &cryptedPointer */

    printf("The new value is: %s", cryptedPointer);

    return 0;
}
```

There are other issues with this code though. After the call to `pointeeChanger()`, `cryptedPointer` no longer points to the `crypted` array. I suspect you actually wanted to change the contents of that array. This code fails to do that.

To change the value of `crypted[]` you will need to use `strcpy()` or (preferably) `strncpy()`. Also you will need to watch the size of the `crypted[]` array - `"something"` is longer than `"nothing"` and will cause a buffer overflow unless `crypted[]` is made larger.

This code will modify the original `crypted[]` array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 64

/*
 * Only char* required because we are not modifying the
 * original pointer passed in - we are modifying what it
 * points to.
 */
int pointeeChanger(char* writeLocation)
{
    /*
     * In C, you need to use a function like strcpy or strncpy to overwrite a
     * string with another string. Prefer strncpy because it allows you to
     * specify a maximum size to copy, which helps to prevent buffer overruns.
     */
    strncpy(writeLocation, "something", MAX_STR_LEN);

    /* strncpy doesn't automatically add a \0 */
    writeLocation[MAX_STR_LEN] = '\0';

    return 0;
}


int main(void)
{
    /*
     * The +1 is because an extra character is required for the 
     * null terminator ('\0')
     */
    char crypted[MAX_STR_LEN + 1] = "nothing";

    pointeeChanger(crypted);

    printf("The new value is: %s", crypted);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: +1 sometimes I can't see the forest for the trees. nice catch. Kipt, you need a `strcpy()` *and* a bigger buffer.

Comment: My thought behind this was: if I send a pointer to a function and call that pointer in that function shouldn't it be also changing the pointee, so the value where the pointer is pointing.

Comment: No, it's exactly like when you call a function with an `int` - the function receives a copy of the variable you pass in, which can be modified as much as you like. Only if you pass a pointer to `int` can you change the value of the `int` itself.

Comment: Yep. Now replace "int" with "pointer to int" in @MatsPetersson's comment. The same reasoning applies.

Comment: So is it correct to say that we can not pass a pointer but we can pass a pointer's pointer, so a pointer that is pointing to cryptedPointer? The point for this code was in the first place to change the crypted var by passing a pointer to a function.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for! It unfortunately also proves that the "simple" things take a lot of language insight. Thanks again for helping me out! Btw is it safe to say that we are changing the content from a var by completely altering the content through a pointer?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer to show how to change the original `crypted[]` array. Unlike the original code though, a pointer to a pointer is not required. This might seem contradictory. @dasblinkenlight's answer is correct - C strings are not very good for learning pointers, since they are themselves implemented using pointers. Notice in my new code that `crypted` is passed in, but the parameter inside `pointeeChanger` is a `char *`.

Comment: Yes, we are changing the content of a variable via a pointer to that variable.

Answer (score 4):

C strings are not the best material to learn pointers, because they are implemented as pointers to `char`. Let's use `int` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pointeeChanger(int* writeLocation) {
    // Using dereference operator "*"
    *writeLocation = 42; // something
}

int main(void) {
    int crypted = 0; // Nothing
    pointeeChanger(&cryptedPointer); // Taking an address with "&"
    printf("The new value is: %d", crypted);
    return 0;
}
```

This works as expected.

Modifying strings in place is a lot harder, because you are forced to deal with memory management issues. Specifically, the string into which you copy must have enough space allocated to fit the new string. This wouldn't work with "nothing" and "something", because the replacement is longer by two characters.

Answer (score 2):

It depends slightly on what you actually want to do:

Do you want to change what `cryptedPointer` is pointing to, or change the content that `cryptedPointer` is pointing at?

The second can be done by:

```
  strcpy(writeLocation, "something");
```

Beware that if `something` is longer than what the original string's size, you'll overflow the buffer, which is a bad thing. So to fix this, you'd have to have `char crypted[10] = "nothing";`, to make space for the string "something".

You can clearly also do something like:

```
 writeLocation[2] = 'f';
 writeLocation[3] = 'f';
```

and have the `printf` print "noffing"

but if you want to do the first variant, then you need to pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
int pointeeChanger(char** writeLocation) {

    *writeLocation = "something";
    return 0;
}
```

And then call:

```
pointeeChanger(&cryptedPointer);
```

Note that when this returns, `cruptedPointer` is pointing at a constant string that can't be modified, where your original `crypted` can be modified.

Comment: So dont get me wrong but in this case we cant change the first pointer so we are editing the pointer's pointer? Sorry for the double pointer construction

Comment: Yes, just like you can't edit an integer inside a function, but need to pass a pointer to an integer. [This is why `int x; scanf("%d", &x);` needs `&x` and not `x` - same thing, `x` can't be modified without us passing along WHERE `x` is - otherwise, it's just a copy of `x`]

Comment: But how can I change the value of crypted then? Because after the function it still has the same value.

Comment: Right, my first two suggestions are ones that change the value inside `crypted`. The other suggestion shows you how to make `cryptedPointer` point to something else. Which is it you want to do?

Comment: The main purpose for this script was for school. I need to write a program that reads files and then puts the containing information into a char[]. So I thought it would come in handy to make a function that accepts a pointer and a filename, in this way the variables in the main part could be altered without passing them to a function. So yeah I am looking for a way to alter the crypted var.

Comment: So, then `strcpy` or `cryptedPointer[x] = 'a';` will be the "right" thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that Tom is hired by Sally to break knuckles for the mafia.

Pass-by-value: If Sally tells Tom to count the number of knuckles he breaks at work today, then Sally has no way of knowing which number Tom has come up with until he returns from the road. They both have a copy of the number "zero" in their heads to begin with, but Tom's number might increase throughout the course of the day.

Note the word "copy". When you pass-by-value to a function, you're passing a copy of the object. When you modify the object within a function, you're modifying the copy instead of the original.

Pass-by-reference: If Sally tells Tom to tally the number of knuckles he breaks in the sky, then she (and anyone else who's interested) can refer to the sky. By changing the sky, Tom would also be changing Sally's number.

edit: C doesn't have pass-by-reference, though it does have pointers, which are reference types. Passing a pointer is still pass-by-value, and a copy with the same pointer value is still formed. Hence, your assignment is to the copy, not the original.

Comment: hehe thanks for the story, I now understand the underlying problem